# Delete Comment Box in right side of SP items

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powershell, modern-experience, comments

How do I remove the COMMENT box showing in the right side of SharePoint list items?

It just shows up recently with no reason.

Thanks much

[image: Comment Box]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Ganesh Sanap’s Answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/287765/delete-comment-box-in-right-side-of-sp-items#comment305688_287766):

This is a new feature named **[Microsoft Lists: comments - built on SharePoint](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=64169)**, currently rolling out in SharePoint Online.

The feature is not possible to be disabled at the site or list level currently, but only **at the organization level** by changing the `CommentsOnListItemsDisabled` parameter in the `Set-SPOTenant` PowerShell cmdlet.

You must be a **SharePoint Admin** or **Global Admin** in your tenant to turn the feature off.

Answer (score 0):

This is a new feature released by Microsoft and currently rolling out in SharePoint Online tenants.

You can find more details about it at: [All you need to know about Commenting in Lists](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/09/all-you-need-to-know-about-commenting-in-lists/).

You can disable comments in SharePoint online lists using PowerShell.

Use below command:

```
Set-SPOTenant -CommentsOnListItemsDisabled $true
```

> **-CommentsOnListItemsDisabled**
>
> Disables or enables commenting functionality on list items. PARAMVALUE: `$true` | `$false`

**Microsoft documentation**: [Set-SPOTenant](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/set-spotenant)

**Reference**: [How to Enable/Disable the commenting in SharePoint Online/Microsoft Lists](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/09/how-to-enable-disable-the-commenting-in-sharepoint-online-microsoft-lists/)

Comment: could you please provide more details how to do that in powershell? sorry, i'm just very new with SP and never code before. thanks

Comment: Ideally such activities should be done by your SharePoint administrators. But If you want to do this you can have a look at: [Get started with SharePoint Online Management Shell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/connect-sharepoint-online). This is very good documentation to get started with and it is very easy to use SharePoint PowerShell. Let me know if you need more help!

Comment: Hi @Emma, Did you try this solution? is it working for you? If you have any issue using above solution you can comment here. I will help further.

Answer (score 0):

Controlling comments at the list level ***should be*** released this month (June 2021).

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=70706

[image]